# Add querystring parameters and generate a SEF URL

Tags: joomla-3.x, sef, seo, jinput, non-sef-url

we have a custom PHP script which is running under JUMI to perform and display some data.

The custom script is accessible to a SEF url such as

```
http://www.mysite.com/jumi-script
```

which is a rewritten version of

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_jumi&view=application&fileid=11&Itemid=271
```

Now we would like to filter data applying parameters such as

```
category=mycat&place=myplace
```

like this

```
/index.php?option=com_jumi&view=application&fileid=11&Itemid=271&category=mycat&place=myplace
```

and we would like to obtain a SEF url like this

```
/jumi-script/mycat/myplace
```

and process these variables in my script with

```
$mycat = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->get('category');

$myplace = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->get('place');
```

How do we obtain this? we are testing the

```
$currentUrl =& JURI::getInstance();
$currentUrl->setVar( 'mycat', $catvalue );
```

but we are loosing the rest of the query string. Can the above be achieved?
Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: How do you do the rewritten url? If in .htaccess, could you show the rewrite?

Comment: @PepLainez
we use the regular joomla htaccess
https://docs.joomla.org/Preconfigured_htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the router implementation of com_jumi here https://github.com/BonavalMultimedia/com_jumi/blob/master/com_jumi_bnvl/router.php for me it seems it doesn't handle extra parameters when sef is on (see JumiParseRoute function).

You need to modify this function to check for your extra parameters and add them to the `$vars` array, so they will be available using `JInput` or `JRequest` if you are on Joomla versions before 3.0

To check the parameters, simply look if they are defined in the `$segments` parameter.

To see if you have a `category` , a `place` or both you need to determine your own criteria or store the possible values anywhere you can check for sure which value 'type' is in every segment.

**Example**: my criteria is that URLs will always be jumi/category/place . Then:

```
$vars['category'] = $segments[1];
$vars['place'] = $segments[2];
```

Of course, you must check that `$segment` indexes are defined and do whatever checking you need.

Maybe you will want to produce SEF urls when creating the routes. Then you should modify the `JumiBuildRoute` function to follow your criteria.

#### Alternative to edit code

If you don't want to edit the routing code of the component then use an URL like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/jumi-script?category=mycat&place=myplace
```

to get your script. Now, both values should be accessible through `JInput` or `JRequest` on older Joomla versions.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

For your url `/index.php?option=com_jumi&view=application&fileid=11&Itemid=271&category=mycat&place=myplace` :

```
$JInput    = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$myRequest = $JInput->getArray(array(
    'option'  =>'',
    'view'    =>'',
    'fileid'  =>'', 
    'Itemid'  =>'',
    'category'=>'',
    'place'   =>''
));
```

Or if you want to **filter** the input:

```
$myRequest = $JInput->getArray(array(
    'option'  =>'word',
    'view'    =>'alnum',
    'fileid'  =>'int', 
    'Itemid'  =>'int',
    'category'=>'string',
    'place'   =>'string'
));
```

each input will return value as filtered type, or `NULL` if there is no value.

Comment: hi cwps, thank you for taking time to respond my question.

Comment: The problem is not in fitering, but in rewriting. I need that
http://www.idea.devsite.it/preventivo-per?categoria=costruzione-piscine

Comment: sorry, but this is not taking the enter as a new line.... ;-(
http://www.mysite.com/page-per?categoria=mycat
shoud became something like
http://www.mysite.com/mycat
after the rewrite the filtering can be used, but right now is that the rewrite is not working as supposed....